# Writing into csv file with specific name

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe say des_frame which I get by processing a txt file say split_aa. I want to write into a csv file which should have a name 'OP_aa'.
If the input is  split_bb, the output should be OP_bb and so on. How can I do  this.

I tried 
des_frame.to_csv('output_file',sep='\t')

I don't know how to assign the output_file name specific to the input
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the input filename in a variable and the use it to generate the output filename. Something like:

```
input_file = 'split_aa'
output_file = 'OP_' + input_file.split('_')[1]
```

and use the output_file variable to write to csv:

```
des_frame.to_csv(output_file, sep='\t')
```

Comment: Thanks, if give my input_file from the command line as sys.argv[1] and file1 = sys.argv[1] and then of = 'OP' + file1.split('_')[1] I get 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'. How can I read the filename in as a string?

Comment: Try `of = 'OP' + str(file1).split('_')[1]`

Comment: Tried this..still get the same error. I have to figure out a way to read in the file name as  a string and then split at'_'

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use regular expressions to get the right letters from input file (split_aa.txt) and then use the %s style to get the right text for the output file.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

input_file = 'split_aa.txt'
suffix = re.sub('.*_','',input_file)
suffix = re.sub('.txt','',suffix)

des_frame = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2],'b':[6,1]})
des_frame.to_csv('OP_%s.csv' % suffix,sep='\t')
```